# Simplify $n^{(\log_2(n)/\log_2(\log_2(n)))}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I need this solved for an asymptotic analysis of an algorithm but I'm stuck. What does this expression simplify to?

Comment: You can rewrite it in various ways (e.g. using $n^a=\exp (a\ln n),\,\frac{\log_2 x}{\log_2 y}=\frac{\ln x}{\ln y}$), but I'm not sure any of them really "simplify" it.

Answer (score 3):

It is about as simple as it gets. A slightly different version is $2^{(\log_2(n))^2/\log_2(\log_2(n))}.$

Comment: Can it be simplified to the point where we have no exponents or roots?

Comment: What is wrong with the version I wrote? If you want it simpler you have to give up something and that depends on the context of where you came up with the expression. Until you tell us that context, we can't help you.